# Successive AJAX calls in a forEach - why can't I see the results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Note: I know I'm probably doing this the wrong way and I'd like any advice about writing it better.

I have a function that, when given a user id, does calls to two APIs to get
1. A list of all the leagues that userid is in.
2. A list of all users in each of those leagues.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "/api/user/" + userID,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    response.leagues.classic.forEach(element => {
      if (element.short_name == null) {
        myLeagues.push(element.id);
      }
    });

  }
}).then(function() {
  myLeagues.forEach(leagueid => {
    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "/api/league/" + leagueid,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.standings.results.length < 30) {
          response.standings.results.forEach(element => {
            myOpponents.push(element.player_name)
          });
        }
      }
    });
  })
}).then(function() {
  console.log(myOpponents);
  myOpponents.forEach(opponent => {
    console.log(opponent)
  });
})
```

`console.log(myOpponents)` outputs an array with all opponents, as expected

`console.log(opponent)` two lines later doesn't output anything.

Can you explain why that is, and suggest a better way of writing this whole function? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Sounds like you're mixing up `success` and `then`. Don't use both, use either of these, but not both together. `.then`, in fact, will be called upon a success call.

Comment: What does your output for myOpponents look like.

Comment: Please try with this code: https://pastebin.com/qHWAByeQ I've cleaned it up a bit, it should work as intended.

Comment: @briosheje Thank you very much. I really appreciate that

Comment: @briosheje I get an error on results.forEach:not an array. If I console.log it, it's a promise object instead. how am I supposed to access the value of the promise?

Comment: That's weird, it should work since the $.ajax call is returning a promise array. Perhaps jQuery acts differently, so you may try to replace `Promise.all` with `$.when`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709597/wait-until-all-jquery-ajax-requests-are-done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
async function someFunc(userID) {
  let myLeagues = [];
  let myOpponents = [];

  try {
    const results = await $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "/api/user/" + userID,
      dataType: "json"
    });

    results.forEach(element => {
      if (element.short_name == null) {
        myLeagues.push(element.id);
      }
    });

    let leagues = myLeagues.map(leagueid => {
      return $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/api/league/" + leagueid,
        dataType: "json"
      })
    })

    let leagueDatas = await Promise.all(leagues);

    leagueDatas.forEach(val => {
      if (val.standings.results.length < 30) {
        val.standings.results.forEach(element => {
          myOpponents.push(element.player_name)
        });
      }
    })

    myOpponents.forEach(opponent => {
      console.log(opponent)
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // handle error
  }
}
someFunc(1)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for writing this. I get val is undefined in the leagueDatas.map. The ajax call in leagues works because I can give it a success function and see the data, but it seems like the promise never works

Comment: What is the result of console.log(leagues) and leagueDatas, it's hard to guess the structure

Comment: If I console.loge(leagues)  or leagueDatas it's an array of four undefined objects. If I put a success function in the AJAX call and console.log that, it evaluates to the object. It seems to be failing on the promise

Comment: could you link to some fiddle, the output of `results` (first await)

Comment: sorry my bad, `return` was missing in `myLeagues.map` updated answer check now.

Comment: Thank you so much man, I really appreciate it. The return makes sense to me, also